# ffmpeg: minimum components for muxing m4a and raw video?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to build a version of ffmpeg (for android) using the bare minimum number of components (encoders, decoders, parsers etc...), in order to minimize my binary space (don't want to bloat the resulting APK).

The task at hand is to mux an m4a audio with a raw video file into an mp4 file. (x264)

When I compile ffmpeg with all components, it works fine, but I could not figure out which components to include to be able to read in m4a files.

Here is the list of flag we currently use to successfully mux mp3 audio with raw video to create mp4 files.

*Which flags should be added to be able to mux-in m4a files?*

```
--disable-everything \
--enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 \
--enable-encoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-muxer=h264 --enable-parser=h264 \
--enable-decoder=rawvideo \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-hwaccels \
--enable-decoder=mp3 --enable-demuxer=mp3 \
--enable-demuxer=wav --enable-decoder=pcm_s16le --enable-decoder=pcm_s16be --enable-decoder=pcm_s16le_planar \
--enable-encoder=aac --enable-parser=aac \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-encoder=mpeg4 --enable-parser=mpeg4video --enable-demuxer=m4v"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out these are the missing flags:

```
--enable-demuxer=mov --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=aac_latm --enable-encoder=aac --enable-parser=aac --enable-demuxer=aac --enable-bsf=aac_adtstoasc \
```